# MySQL call procedure in every message send in chat program

Tags: mysql, database, google-cloud-sql

My application is a chat application. For every message,

1)I send 'message and friend token for GCM' to server.

2)Server call a procedure in database.

3)Procedure inserts 3 rows to different tables (no select request here) and return LAST_INSERT_ID() as out parameter.

4)Then server send message to friend using GCM and return message_id from database (LAST_INSERT_ID()) to me.

I am using Google App Engine(Java) and Google Cloud Sql (Mysql) as server and database. My problem is I am getting 'Communications link failure last packet sent to the server' error from database randomly. Error is not depend on data size. Maybe error often occurs while sending frequently message.

Okay I know calling database in every message send action is a bad architecture. I can fix it but my problem is that I don't have so much user now. Many applications has over millions users and database is calling hundreds times in second. Why my database can't response every procedure calls.

I tried to delete calling database code from my server and it works much more fast and no error occurs.

Comment: Are you using connection pooling?

Comment: No. I searched and I think this is my answer. Why don't we keep only one connection instead of connection pooling? Because of multithreading?

Comment: Right now you are probably using one connection *per request* which means you are constantly opening and reopening connections which is expensive. There are also safeguards to limit the rate of open connections to avoid overloading the instance.

Comment: I got it. I am asking "can't I use only one connection instead of connection pool?". Singleton connection. In getConnection() method, I will check whether is connection object is null or not. If it is null create new one, else use existing one. Why don't we use it instead of connection pooling?

Comment: Connections are not thread safe. You *could* use one connection but you must "lock" it for use by a single request (this is the same as using a connection pool with a size of 1). I wouldn't recommend it since that single connection would be a single point of failure for your appplication.

Comment: Okay. Thank you really so much. You helped me so much :) Have a nice day.